# How to have login and access settings with a docker image registry

Tags: docker, linux-containers

I am not new to lxc or docker. But I do not have much knowledge on the image registry.
So I decided to get started and followed up tutorials and installation instructions.

And things are working fine in terms of pushing and pulling from my custom registry.

My questions:

The registry does not seem to come with a login/access management system.

1st - What are the overall steps to follow to implement a login (and possibly access) management to a custom registry?

2nd - If this mechanism is implemented, is there a way to use docker login to use that mechanism instead of https://hub.docker.com 's?

Answer (score 0):

To 2nd: By using `docker login /yourregistry`, you can use the login mechanism of docker to login to a specific registry. The credentials are saved as well,
dockerhub is just the default. Unfortunately I don't know how to set up an own registry, personal I'm just using it in my company to pull from our artifactory.